# Entity Framework (EF) code first migration creates only some of the tables

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I am running my initial EF migration trying to create the database.

But only 3 of my 5 domains are being created as tables in the database. No errors occur during migration.

I try to run `SeedData` methods on run, but of course it stops when it tries to save data to the table that does not exist.

I am using EF7. I use DNX to run migrations.

Does anyone know why only 3 of the tables are being created?

Here are the 2 tables that did NOT get created:

```
 // Enumclass, this is not a table
 public enum MatchTypeEnum
 { 
    Group, RoundOf32, RoundOf16, QuarterFinals, SemiFinals, BronzeFinal, Final
 }

 public partial class Match
 {
    [Key]
    public Guid MatchId { get; set; }

    public DateTime KickOffTime { get; set; }
    public int? HomeScore { get; set; }
    public int? AwayScore { get; set; }
    public Guid HomeTeamId { get; set; }
    public Guid AwayTeamId { get; set; }
    public MatchTypeEnum MatchType { get; set; }
    public Guid? GroupId { get; set; }

    public virtual Team HomeTeam { get; set; }
    public virtual Team AwayTeam { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("GroupId")]
    public virtual Group Group { get; set; }
 }

 public enum MatchOutcomeEnum
 {
      H,A,D 
 }

 public partial class Bet
 {
    [Key]
    public Guid BetId { get; set; }

    public Guid UserId { get; set; }
    public Guid MatchId { get; set; }

    public int? HomeScore { get; set; }
    public int? AwayScore { get; set; }

    public MatchOutcomeEnum? MatchOutcome{ get; set; }

    public int? PointsCorrectScore { get; set; }
    public int? PointsBonus { get; set; }
    public int? MultiplyScoreWith { get; set; }
    public int? TotalPointsBet { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("MatchId")]
    public virtual Match MatchBettedOn { get; set; }
}
```

And here are the 3 classes that do get created:

```
public class Team
{
    [Key]
    public Guid TeamId { get; set; }

    public string TeamName { get; set; }
    public string TeamCountry { get; set; }
    public Guid GroupId { get; set; }
    public string LogoUrl { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("GroupId")]
    public virtual Group TeamGroup { get; set; }
}

public enum GroupEnum
{
    GroupA, GroupB, GrooupC, GroupD,GroupE,GroupF, GroupG, GroupH, GroupI
}

/// <summary>
/// The group.
/// </summary>
public partial class Group
{
    [Key]
    public Guid GroupId { get; set; }

    public GroupEnum GroupName { get; set; }
    public int? NumberTeamsProceed { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Team> TeamsInGroup { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Match> MatchesInGroup { get; set; }
}

public class League
{
    [Key]
    public Guid LeagueId { get; set; }

    public string LeagueName { get; set; }
    public bool Public { get; set; }
    public int LeagueNumber { get; set; }
    public string LeagueLink { get; set; }
}
```

The `DbContext`:

```
public class CupBettingContext : DbContext
{
    public CupBettingContext()
    {
        Database.EnsureCreated();
    }

    public DbSet<Group> Groups { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Match> Matches { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Bet> Bets { get; set; }
    public DbSet<League> Leagues { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Team> Teams { get; set; }

    protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
    {
        var connectionString = Startup.Configuration["Data:CupBettingContextConnection"];
        optionsBuilder.UseSqlServer(connectionString);

        base.OnConfiguring(optionsBuilder);
    }
}
```

Thank you for your time :)

---

UPDATE:

It worked after I I removed the two lines from the class Match:

```
    public virtual Team HomeTeam { get; set; }
    public virtual Team AwayTeam { get; set; }
```

Strange that it ran the migration :/

If anyone is still reading this question, how can I add those virtual object without getting an error?

Comment: Do you perhaps miss those classes as DbSets in your DbContext?

Comment: I added the dbcontext to the original question. As you can see there, the DbSets are there.

Comment: I haven't used DNX yet but I know sometimes EF 6 will miss changes if you haven't built the project after making changes.

Comment: How does your initial migration code look like? Does it contain those two missing tables?

Comment: @DrewJordan: I built the project.

Comment: @Edin: Yes, the tables are both in the migrationFile and the ContextModelSnapshot. It looks like everything worked fine during the migration, but the tables are not in the DB.

Comment: You may try to run the migration on the empty DB and see what statements get executed. I do not know if it is possible to updata database -Verbose with DNX. Maybe something like this: `dnx ef database update —verbose`. That will let you inspect the statements which get executed during the migration and you can inspect the DB state afterwards.